# Reading sql & csv data to data table

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to merge sql and csv data to data table.

Load part of sql table to dt table works fine... When I try csv read to dt, getting data types not match issue.

As I am new to c# , I do not know how to convert datatypes,
Can some one suggest and guide me to handle this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: provide some code please. please read [ask]

Comment: Are you using a library to read the CSV file, or are you doing it by yourself?